# Newton-Euler formulation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, centrifugal-force, gyroscopes, coriolis-effect

How to find the translational and rotational equations of motion when the center of gravity does not coincide with the origin of the fixed-body rotating frame?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The dynamical equations governing the translation and rotation of a rigid body are

$\dfrac{d \mathbf{Q}}{dt} = \mathbf{R}^{e}$
$\dfrac{d \mathbf{\Gamma}_H}{dt} = -\dot{\mathbf{x}}_H \times \mathbf{Q} + \mathbf{M}_H^{e}$,

being $\mathbf{Q}$ the momentum of the body, $\mathbf{R}^e$ the resultant of the external forces acting on the body, $H$ the pole w.r.t the angular momentum $\mathbf{\Gamma}_H$ and the moment $\mathbf{M}_H$ are expressed, $\mathbf{x}_H(t)$ is the position of the pole.

In these equations $H$ is an arbitrary geometrical point.

If you need to write the momentum and the angular momentum in terms of the angular velocity $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ and the velocity of a point $P$ that is not the center of mass, you can easily verify (using the rigid body motion) that

- $\mathbf{Q} = m \mathbf{v}_G = m \left[ \mathbf{v}_P + \boldsymbol\omega \times (\mathbf{r}_G - \mathbf{r}_P ) \right] = m  \mathbf{v}_P - m (\mathbf{r}_G - \mathbf{r}_P )\times \omega = m \mathbf{v}_P + \mathbb{S}_P \cdot \boldsymbol\omega$;
- $\mathbf{\Gamma}_H = \displaystyle \int_V \rho (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_H) \times \mathbf{v} = \dots$ using the definition of the angular momentum you can express it w.r.t. the point you need; as an example, if you know the tensor of inertia w.r.t. the point $P$, we can write:

  $\mathbf{\Gamma}_H = \displaystyle \int_V \rho (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_H) \times \mathbf{v} = \displaystyle \int_V \rho [(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_P) + (\mathbf{r}_P - \mathbf{r}_H) ] \times [ \mathbf{v}_P + \boldsymbol\omega \times (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_P)]$

  and rewrite it as

  $\mathbf{\Gamma}_H = \displaystyle \int_V \rho (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_P) \times \mathbf{v}_P + (\mathbf{r}_P - \mathbf{r}_H) \times \int_V \rho  \mathbf{v}_P - \int_V \rho (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_P) \times (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_P) \times  \boldsymbol\omega - (\mathbf{r}_P - \mathbf{r}_H) \times \int_V \rho (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_P) \times  \boldsymbol\omega =$
  $\qquad \quad = m(\mathbf{r}_G - \mathbf{r}_P) \times \mathbf{v}_P + (\mathbf{r}_P - \mathbf{r}_H) \times m  \mathbf{v}_P + \mathbb{I}_P \cdot  \boldsymbol\omega - (\mathbf{r}_P - \mathbf{r}_H) \times m (\mathbf{r}_G - \mathbf{r}_P) \times  \boldsymbol\omega = \dots$
  and so on

Comment: I’m just curious… In what country is $Q$ momentum, $R$ force, $\Gamma$ angular momentum, $M$ torque, and $H$ a point?

Comment: Call them as you wish, but salute from Italy. But I guess that not everyone in Italy would use the same symbol. This comes from analytical mechanics in Milan

Comment: Grazie mille, basics.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

\begin{align*}
  & \textbf{Translation}\\
  &m\,\vec{a}_{CM}=\vec{F}_{CM}+\vec{F}_P\\\\
  &\vec{F}_P=-m\left[\vec{\omega}\times\left(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}_{CM}\right)+
  2\left(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{v}_{CM}\right)+
  \vec{\dot{\omega}}\times\vec{r}_{CM}\right]\\\\
   & \textbf{Rotation}\\
   &\mathbf{ I}_P\vec{\dot{\omega}}=\vec{u}\times\left(\vec{F}_{CM}+\vec{F}_P\right)-
   \vec{\omega}\times\left(\mathbf{I}_P\,\vec{\omega}\right)+\vec\tau_{CM}\\
   &\mathbf{I}_P=\mathbf{I}_{CM}+m\,\mathbf{U}^T\mathbf{U}\quad,
   \mathbf{U}= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-u_{{z}}&u_{{y}}\\ u_{
{z}}&0&-u_{{x}}\\ -u_{{y}}&u_{{x}}&0\end {array}
 \right]
 \end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 &\textbf{Translation plus Rotation}\\
  &\begin{bmatrix}
     m\,E_3 & -m\,[\mathbf{r}_{CM}]^\times \\
     0 & \mathbf{I}_P-m\,[\mathbf{\vec{u}\times\vec r_{CM}}]^\times \\
   \end{bmatrix} 
   \begin{bmatrix}
     \vec{a}_{CM} \\
     \vec{\dot{\omega}} \\
   \end{bmatrix}
   =\begin{bmatrix}
      \vec{F}_{PR} \\
      \vec{u}\times\left(\vec{F}_{CM}+\vec{F}_{PR}\right)-
   \vec{\omega}\times\left(\mathbf{I}_P\,\vec{\omega}\right)+\vec\tau_{CM} \\
    \end{bmatrix}\\\\
    &\vec{F}_{PR}=-m\left[\vec{\omega}\times\left(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}_{CM}\right)+
  2\left(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{v}_{CM}\right)
  \right]
 \end{align*}

- $~\vec F~$ forces
- $~\vec\tau~$ external torque
- $~\mathbf I~$ Inertia
- $~CM~$ center of mass
- $~P~$ pseudo

---

\begin{align*}
  &[\mathbf{\vec{u}\times\vec r_{CM}}]^\times=
 \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & -z & y \\
   z & 0 & -x \\
   -y & x & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}\quad, \text{where}\quad
  \begin{bmatrix}
                              x \\
                              y \\
                              z \\
                            \end{bmatrix}=\vec{u}\times\vec{r}_{CM}\\  
 \end{align*}

**Notice**

all vector components  are given in the Rotation-Frame, thus  the position vector of the center of mass in inertial system is:

$$\vec r_I(t)=\mathbf R(\varphi_i)\vec r_{CM}(t)$$

where $~\varphi_i=\varphi_i(t)~,i=1..3~$ are the Euler angles.

to get the result, you need additional  three differential equations which  are

with the rotation matrix $~\mathbf R(\varphi_i)~$ you obtain the angular velocity vector $~\vec\omega~$

$$\vec\omega=\mathbf J_R(\vec \varphi)\,\vec{\dot{\varphi}}\quad\Rightarrow\\
\vec{\dot{\varphi}}=[\mathbf{J}_R]^{-1}\,\vec\omega$$

all together you obtain 9 first order differential equations